# jQuery event handler doesn't work or doesn't fire only on first page load, but works after inspecting the dom after a refresh

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with ie9 and jQuery.

In Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, my click events work on anchor tags, but in IE9, the event fails to fire or something happens. it only happens on the first page load when i have nothing in cache, and it doesn't work.

I click on a link, and no menu fades in, however when I refresh the page, and inspect it with f12 developer tools, it works.

It's weird, works in every other browser and IE9 after inspecting the dom. Thank you for any help.

ok after looking at the page, i have the same type of event registering with another group of links that work fine in ie9.

i think its having a problem with this selector:

```
   var catTopSelector= '#pc_lhs_top_ul > li:not( #main_menu_top )';
   var catBottomSelector= '#pc_lhs_bottom_ul > li:not( #main_menu_bottom )';
```

for some reason it only works after inspecting. works in all other browsers.

UPDATED ANSWER:

ok, i found out why. i had a console.log in the code right before the animation, and because console is only available when the debugger is opened, it would crash right before the animation. thanks again guys.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: i get no errors, and by the time i try to look in the console, and inspect it, it works fine. but the initial click doesnt.

Comment: after looking at google, apparently theres a child selector bug in ie9?

Comment: Do you have any asynchronous calls in your code?

Comment: yes, yes i do.  basically that selector is used with .on to enable click events, and those events basically animate the ul and li's. the code also uses jquery promises.

Comment: ok so ive pinpointed the problem, its not the selector. i tried this jsfiddle and it worked in ie9: http://jsfiddle.net/wGV8A/6/

Comment: the problem is i have a namespace added, and when i first load the webpage with an empty cache, i have two boolean values that are initialized to true for some reason when they should be initialized to false, the animations are nested in that conditional, thats why its not animating, but why?

Comment: Please post your solution as an **answer** rather than altering your question, you can then accept that answer so future users might be helped

Comment: i tried to answer my post, but i have a reputation under 10, so i updated my answer until 8 hours would pass, so i could answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found out why. i had a console.log in the code right before the animation, and because console is only available when the debugger is opened, it would crash right before the animation!